# How to prevent the playing of multiple iframe youtube videos when playing a single iframe video

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-api

I am playing a multiple  based on the youtube player api, when i click on single player it gets playing ,and when  click second player,the first player is displaying and playing simultaneously with second player,

Can anyone tell me how can i prevent the playing of multiple videos when playing a single video

Here is my Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
    <?php
        for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
        {
        ?>
            <div class="youtubeplayer" playerid='player<?=$i?>' style="cursor:pointer">
                <div id="player<?=$i?>">player<?=$i?></div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;

 $(function()
      {
          $('.youtubeplayer').click(function()
          {         
            var playerid=$(this).attr('playerid');
            player = new YT.Player(playerid , 
            {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: 'kK42LZqO0wA',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });

          });
      });

 function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event)
      { 
        if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
        {
            alert('playing');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('paused');
        }
      }

 function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Do you want to play the videos asynchronously or pause the other videos when a new video starts to play?

Answer (score 0):

This **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ3vB/)** works for me without playing simultaneously using three static html divs

```
<div class="youtubeplayer" playerid='player1' style="cursor:pointer">
      <div id="player1">player</div>
</div>
```